# Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator : CQL error?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have below table in CQL-

```
create table test (
    employee_id text,
    employee_name text,
    value text,
    last_modified_date timeuuid,
    primary key (employee_id)
   );
```

I inserted couple of records in the above table like this which I will be inserting in our actual use case scenario-

```
insert into test (employee_id, employee_name, value, last_modified_date) values ('1', 'e27',  'some_value', now());
insert into test (employee_id, employee_name, value, last_modified_date) values ('2', 'e27',  'some_new_value', now());
insert into test (employee_id, employee_name, value, last_modified_date) values ('3', 'e27',  'some_again_value', now());
insert into test (employee_id, employee_name, value, last_modified_date) values ('4', 'e28',  'some_values', now());
insert into test (employee_id, employee_name, value, last_modified_date) values ('5', 'e28',  'some_new_values', now());
```

Now I was doing select query for -  give me all the employee_id for employee_name `e27`.

```
select employee_id from test where employee_name = 'e27';
```

And this is the error I am getting -

```
Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator
Perhaps you meant to use CQL 2? Try using the -2 option when starting cqlsh.
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

My use cases are in general -

1. Give me everything for any of the employee_name?
2. Give me everything for what has changed in last 5 minutes?
3. Give me the latest employee_id and value for any of the employee_name?
4. Give me all the employee_id for any of the employee_name?

I am running Cassandra 1.2.11

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The general rule is simple: "you can only query by columns that are part of the key". As an explanation all other queries would require a complete scan of the tables which might mean a lot of data sifting.

There are things that can modify this rule:

1. use secondary indexes for columns with low cardinality (more details [here](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77))
2. define multi-column keys (e.g. `PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2)`; which would allow queries like `col1 = value1` and `col1 = value1 and col2 COND`)
3. use `ALLOW FILTERING` in queries. This will result in a warning as Cassandra will have to sift through a lot of data and there will be no performance guarantees. For more details see [details of ALLOW FILTERING in CQL](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694413/alllow-filtering-data-modeling-in-cql)

Comment: For your reference, you can create a secondary key with 'CREATE INDEX ON tests (employee_name);'

Comment: The link in `1` hits a 500 consistenly

Comment: Then it throws another error about Non PRIMARY key. Note: In my example the column is lastname.

 { [ResponseError: Non PRIMARY KEY lastname found in where clause]
  name: 'ResponseError',
  message: 'Non PRIMARY KEY lastname found in where clause',
  info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
  code: 8704,
  query: 'UPDATE users SET age = 36 WHERE lastname = \'Jones\'' }

Answer (score 16):

Cassandra take a little getting used to :)  Some of us have been spoiled by some of the extra stuff RDBMS does for you that you do not get for free from noSql.

If you think back on a regular RDBMS table, if you SELECT on a column that has no index, the DB must do a full-table scan to find all the matches you seek.  This is a no-no in Cassandra, and it will complain if you try to do this.  Imagine if you found 10^32 matches to this query?  It is not a reasonable ask.

In your table, you have coded *PRIMARY KEY(employee_id);* this is the row's primary and unique identifying key.  **You can now SELECT * from TEST where employee_id='123';**  this is perfectly reasonable and Cassandra will happily return the result.

However, your **SELECT from TEST WHERE employee_name = 'e27';** tells Cassandra to go and read EVERY record until it finds a match on 'e27'.  With no index to rely on, it politely asks you to 'forget it'.

If you want to filter on a column, make sure you have an index on that column so that Cassandra can performs the filtering you need.