# why cql query long time

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

My query:

```
cqlsh:mynap_db> select complete_row from tbl_rowsxml_map  where cache_type_name='IncomingCache' and user_id ='34014'  limit 1 ALLOW FILTERING;

 complete_row
--------------

(0 rows)
```

If it returns `0 rows` then why does it take such a long time to execute?

Please help me to understand the reason.

Comment: How many rows are there in your table tbl_rowsxml_map?

Answer (score 4):

`ALLOW FILTERING` is a reason. That means that your schema not allowing you to run this query effectively, so, you allowing Cassandra itself to select much more data from every node and filter data after. Usually is a quite non-effective operation.

Check Datastax' [explanation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) for details or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694413/alllow-filtering-data-modeling-in-cql).

Comment: Agree.  ALLOW FILTERING is the root of all evil.